# Group Managed Service Account (gMSA): get authorized hosts / install-adserviceaccount unknown error

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

After having successfully created a Group Managed Service Account (gMSA) using the command below:

```
add-adserviceaccount -name gmsaAccount -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount gmsaGroup -DNSHostName gmsaAccount.test.local
```

I am having trouble to have this account installed on the targeted hosts (members of gmsaGroup group). I wonder if the problem is not related to the hosts associated with the service account.

Is there a way (powershell command?) to verify which hosts are associated and authorized with a group managed service account.

I tried `get-adserviceaccount -identity gmsaAccount | fl *` but nothing related to hosts or `principalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount` is displayed.

For information, when i try to run the `install-adserviceaccount` on a target Windows2012R2 host, i get a useless "unknown error" message (no error code).

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have at least one 2012 DC?
2. Did you prep the domain with Add-KDSRootKey?
3. After you added the computers to gmsaGroup, were they rebooted to get a new token that reflects the new group membership?
4. When you create the account, I think you need to use "PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword" instead of "PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount"

The cmdlet to create a new gMSA is "New-ADServiceAccount" not "Add-ADServiceAccount"

Process overview http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/12/17/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts.aspx

Comment: #4 is what tripped me up the first time I was messing around with gMSAs, mostly because I was tab-completing the argument and "Delegate" comes before "Retrieve" and didn't notice the difference.